# How to get a previous date using a reference to a file with the date command?

Tags: date

I'm trying to get Previous date of reference file.

What I've tried :

```
[rahul@testsrv]$ date +%F -r /tmp/ftpbkp.log
2013-08-27

[rahul@testsrv]$ date +%F -r /tmp/ftpbkp.log -d "1 day ago"
date: the options to specify dates for printing are mutually exclusive
Try `date --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A note of warning:

```
$ date -r ~/a
Sun 28 Oct 23:12:00 GMT 2012
$ LC_ALL=C date -r ~/a
Sun Oct 28 23:12:00 GMT 2012
```

As output, `date` outputs the date in the user's local format. As input to `-d` GNU `date` is more picky on the format though:

```
$ date -d "$(date -r ~/a) - 1 day"
date: invalid date ‘Sun 28 Oct 23:12:00 GMT 2012 - 1 day’
```

Fixing locale to C fixes that  issue:

```
$ export LC_ALL=C
$ date -d "$(date -r ~/a) - 1 day"
Sun Oct 28 00:12:00 BST 2012
```

But note how the date is still 2012-10-28, though now in summer time. That's because 24 hours before that date in Britain, we were still the same day.

Now, if you want the day before, you'd have to write it:

```
date -d "$(date -r /tmp/file.ref +'%F -1 day')" +%F
```

Answer (score 4):

```
LC_ALL=C date -d "$(LC_ALL=C date -r /tmp/ftpbkp.log) - 1 day" +%F
```

If *GNU date* is not available:

```
perl -MPOSIX -le'
  print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", localtime +(stat shift)[9] - 24*60*60)
  ' /tmp/ftpbkp.log
```

Comment: yes.. after lots of tried, Just I also found the same , thanks

Comment: That will not work in all locales, even English locales (you may want to call both `date`s with `LC_ALL=C`). That may not work as you want around daylight saving time change.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, as usual, thanks for your valuable comments!

Comment: Thanks Sir, If I use `LC_ALL=C` at top in script, is that enough ? actually I didn't understood why use `LC_ALL=C`. http://paste.ubuntu.com/6036642/

Comment: Note that the perl one will also be affected by DST change.

Answer (score 2):

```
date -r /tmp/ftpbkp.log +%s | awk '{print strftime("%F", $1 - (24*60*60) );}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-d` option is used for specifying a different time than the current time. You asked `date` command to format the last modification time of file `/tmp/ftpbkp.log` according the format `%F` and additionally you passed it another time specified by `-d` option. These option are mutually exclusive. But there is a trick how to combine it:

```
date -d "`date -r /tmp/ftpbkp.log`" - 1 day"
```

Comment: The backticks are deprecated, use `$()` instead. Also what else does this add beyond what Dimitre's answer provided?

Comment: I wrote it at the same time so basically nothing :-)

Comment: @slm, good comment up there. You should use `$()` command substitution all the time since it offers more flexibility in nesting commands and avoiding entering sometimes unnecessary `" "` double quotes or `' '` single quotes

Comment: @val0x00ff, would you care to expand how `$()` avoids entering quotes?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I am not saying it avoids entering quotes. What I am saying is: When using backticks ```` You need to use more quotes to escape other quotes which will make a line of code illegible. So nested quoting inside `$()` is far more convenient. Compare these two

 `x=$(grep "$(dirname "$somepathpath")" file)`
  x=`grep "\`dirname "$somepath"\`" `file`

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082